# Magnum Gothic font being used instead of Nanum Gothic in Korea

Tags: php, css, wordpress, fonts

So I have a question and wanted to see if anyone has ever come across something like this..

So basically, I'm running wordpress sites from other nations and have fonts that get applied to specific wordpress sites depending on language. I have the 'Nanum Gothic' font applied on the Korean site.

**Description**:
From my view (United States based) - I'm seeing the 'Nanum Gothic' font which is correct! It's supposed to show that but their seeing another font.
[image]

**Problem**:
My users in Korea are seeing the 'Magnum Gothic' font, which has no reference in my wordpress files at all - How could this be possible? Could there be restrictions in Korea that overwrites my Nanum Gothic font?

**I have absolutely no reference of Magnum Gothic anywhere in my code or template.**

**Reference**: _variables.scss

```
Korean font family based on local team request
$korean: $whitney, 'Nanum Gothic', sans-serif;
```

**References**: theme-rtl.css / project-rtl.css / project.css / theme.css

```
/**
 * Font family for Korean site
 */
html[lang="ko-KR"] body {
  font-family: "Whitney A", "Whitney B", "Nanum Gothic", sans-serif; }
  html[lang="ko-KR"] body h1, html[lang="ko-KR"] body h2, html[lang="ko-KR"] body h3, html[lang="ko-KR"] body h4, html[lang="ko-KR"] body h5, html[lang="ko-KR"] body h6 {
    font-family: "Whitney A", "Whitney B", "Nanum Gothic", sans-serif; }
```

Has anyone dealt with something like this? Is there a VPN that I'm able to use that I can view a webpage from a Korean side?

Thanks so much for all the help!

Comment: i'm not entirely sure, but shouldn't the `lang` attribute just be "ko"? edit: nvm, didn't know you could include the country code there too

Comment: so, i researched a little and this is really interesting. i came across [this](https://theme.co/apex/forums/topic/typography-how-can-i-use-korean-google-nanum-fonts/) and was wondering if it could help declaring the font in a child-theme?

Comment: I can't even find that font using google: [`"magnum gothic" +font`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22magnum+gothic%22+font). Ask for proof ?

Comment: So I've come to the conclusion that it's using my "Installed" Nanum Gothic font on my machine.

I've disabled that, but it's still not referencing to Magnum Gothic at all.